# Another condition for bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph. Then prove $G$ is bipartite if and only if for all subgraphs $H$ of $G$ with no isolated vertices. $\alpha(H)=\beta'(H)$.

Here $\alpha(H)$ is the size of the largest independent set. $\beta'$ is the number of edges in a minimal edge covering of $H$.

So far what I've done is incorrect because it results in every graph is bipartite. Maybe someone can tell me where I'm wrong and what I should be doing instead.

$\Rightarrow$ Let $H$ be any subgraph of $G$ with no isolated vertices. Since $H$ has no isolated vertices an edge covering exists. Let $X\subset V(H)$ be an independent set such that $|X|=\alpha$. Define $Y=V(H)\backslash X$. Then all the edges of $X$ go to $Y$. Every vertex in $Y$ must be connected to an edge in $X$ or else we could move that vertex $X$ and increase the size of an independent set. If $Y$ has any edges remove them. The remaining edges is an edge covering of $H$. So $\beta'(H)\geq \alpha(H)$.

Let $X$ be any independent set of $H$ and $Y=V(H)\backslash X$. Then any edge covering $H$ must have at least $|X|$ edges. This is true for all edge coverings so $\beta'(H)\leq \alpha(H)$.

I didn't use bipartite at all and if I assume the theorem is correct it proves all graphs are bipartite.

Any hints of ideas would be very useful. I got stuck on $\Leftarrow$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you’ve reversed your conclusions: if the arguments were correct, the first would show that $\beta'(H)\le\alpha(H)$ and the second that $\beta'(H)\ge\alpha(H)$. The second argument is correct, but the first isn’t. To see where it goes wrong, apply it to $K_3$, a triangle. $X$ contains a single vertex, and both vertices in $Y$ are connected to that same vertex: your edge cover has cardinality $2$, not $1$ (and indeed $\alpha(K_3)=1$ while $\beta'(K_3)=2$).

Assume that $\alpha(H)=\beta'(H)$ for each subgraph $H$ of $G$ having no isolated vertices; you want to show that $G$ must be bipartite. HINT: If not, $G$ contains an odd cycle.

**Edit, 11 Jue 2020**

My original suggested proof for the other direction was nonsense, as pointed out by **Mahsa** in another answer while I was away and now by **PAB** in the comments; I tried to make it easier than it actually is. Here is a corrected version:

The result follows from three standard results.

- Let $\tau(G)$ be the vertex covering number of $G$; then $\alpha(G)+\tau(G)=|V(G)|$.
- Let $\nu(G)$ be the matching number of $G$; then $\nu(G)+\beta'(G)=|V(G)|$ if $G$ has no isolated vertex.
- (König) If $G$ is bipartite, then $\tau(G)=\nu(G)$.

Thus, if $G$ is bipartite and has no isolated points,

$$\beta'(G)=|V(G)|-\nu(G)=|V(G)|-\tau(G)=\alpha(G)\;.$$

The first two are fairly easy to prove.

For the first one, suppose that $X$ is a vertex cover such that $|X|=\tau(G)$. Then $V(G)\setminus X$ is an independent set of vertices, so $\alpha(G)\ge|V(G)|-\tau(G)$, i.e., $$\alpha(G)+\tau(G)\ge|V(G)|\;.$$ On the other hand, if $X$ is an independent set of vertices, and $|X|=\alpha(X)$, then $V(G)\setminus X$ is a vertex cover, so $\tau(G)\le|V(G)|-\alpha(G)$, i.e., $$\alpha(G)+\tau(G)\le|V(G)|\;.$$

For the second, let $F$ be an edge cover such that $|F|=\beta'(G)$. From each component of the graph $\langle V(G),F\rangle$ choose one edge; the result is a matching $M$. The graph $\langle V(G),F\rangle$ has at least $|V(G)|-|F|$ components — $\langle V(G),\varnothing\rangle$ has $|V(G)|$ components, and adding an edge reduces the number of components by at most $1$ — so $$\nu(G)\ge|M|\ge|V(G)|-|F|=|V(G)|-\beta'(G)\;,$$ i.e., $$\nu(G)+\beta'(G)\ge|V(G)|\;.$$

On the other hand, let $M$ be a matching such that $|M|=\nu(G)$. Let $W=V(G)\setminus V(M)$; since $M$ is maximal, $W$ is an independent set of vertices. There are no isolated vertices, so for each $w\in W$ we may choose an edge $e_w$ incident at $w$; let $F=\{e_w:w\in W\}$. Then $F\cup E(M)$ is an edge cover of $G$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\beta'(G)&\le|F|+|E(M)|=|V(G)|-|V(M)|+|E(M)|\\
&=|V(G)|-2\nu(M)+\nu(M)=|V(G)|-\nu(M)\;,
\end{align*}$$

i.e.,

$$\nu(G)+\beta'(G)\le|V(G)|\;.$$

For König’s theorem see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) (and many other places).

Comment: You give very good hints Brian M. Scott. Just what I need but to too much. Thanks alot

Comment: @TheNumber23: You’re very welcome — and thank *you*.

Comment: Hi, I´m stucked in the same excercise and I´m afraid you made a mistake. When you say
$$\alpha(H)=\max\{|V(H)\cap A|,|V(H)\cap B|\}$$
this is not true in genreal. Take $H$ to be a the next graph: as $G$ is bipartite, so is $H$ and let $C$ and $D$ be such parts of $H$, Let $C={a,b,c,d}$ and $D={e,f,g}$ where every vertex on $C$ is adjacent to $e$ and every vertex on $D$ is adjacent to $a$ and being these all the adjacencies in $H$, it is easy to check that $H$ is a subgraph of a bipartite graph, and $\alpha(H)=5$ because ${b,c,d,f,g}$ is an independent set. Could you please check this out?

Comment: I forgot to mention that $H$ has no isolated vertices and your $\alpha(H)=4$ and my $\alpha(H)=5$

Comment: @PAB: You’re right. I think that I know what needs to be done, but it will take a bit of work, and I probably won’t get to it until tomorrow.

Comment: I have to say something, for the first result you mention, it is not true in general, we need G to have no isolated vertices, and in the excercise who must have no isolated vertices is H because isolated vertices on G are irrelevants. I'll read the rest of your proof now. By the way, thanks for your time. Greetings

Answer (score 2):

I think the proof is not true. There are some bipartite graphs with no isolated vertices in which
$\alpha(H)\neq \max\{|V(H)\cap A|,|V(H)\cap B|\}=\beta'(H)$

For example. We have vertices $1,2,3,4$ in part $A$ and vertices $5,6,7,8$  in part $B$. The vertex $4$ is adjacent to all vertices of $B$ and vertex $5$ is adjacent to all vertices of $A$.
This graph has a stable set of size at least $6$. But both parts of graph have size $4$.

And why $\max\{|V(H)\cap A|,|V(H)\cap B|\}=\beta'(H)$?